# AWS: How to manage instance ppk or pem files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

My AWS instance pem file got exposed to few persons. How can I invalidate that and create a new pem file from my instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create NEW PublicKey and PrivateKey.
2. Copy Newly created publicKey to `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` or `/home/ubutu/.ssh/authorized_keys`
3. Delete Old publicKey( in `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` or `/home/ubutu/.ssh/authorized_keys`) which is relevant to shared PEM key.
4. Access the instance using newly created privateKey.
   That's it.

Comment: I'd add that you can create this in the AWS console if you'd like and you should also remove the old one there so it doesn't get used again.

Answer (score 2):

When an Amazon EC2 instance is launched with the Amazon Linux AMI (and a few other Linux AMIs), the public half of the nominated keypair is copied to:

```
/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then, users can login to `ec2-user` by using the private half of the keypair.

Therefore, to change your login credentials:

- Generate a new PEM key: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f keypair.pem`

  - This generates two files: `keypair.pem` (private) and `keypair.pem.pub` (public)
- Remove the existing entry from `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` (The name of the keypair is stored at the end of the entry)
- Add the contents of `keypair.pem.pub` to the `authorized_keys` file

You can then login to `e2-user` using the new keypair.